# Add on ready to my code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, onready

I'm trying to make a list that allows a user to submit issues. Im using knockout and i can get it to do exactly what i wanted it to do but when i try to debug in microsoft visual studios it does not work they way I want it to. When I debug, the page opens the same as in the fiddle except the "test issue" is missing from the issue list. Also you can type in the add issue text box but when you hit submit it clears and does not add to the issue list

I was told I needed to add an onready, but im still new to learning how to code and am unsure of

A.How to do it
B. Where to put it

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/rCB9V/

and here is my code

IssueList ( html )

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Issue List</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Issuelist.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Issuelistcss.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class='issuelist'>

<form data-bind="submit:addIssue">
    Add Issue: <input type="text" data-bind='value:issueToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: issueToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
</form>

<p>Your Issues:</p>
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:allIssues,   selectedOptions:selectedIssues"> </select>

<div>
    <button data-bind="click: removeSelected, enable: selectedIssues().length >  0">Remove</button>
    <button data-bind="click: sortIssues, enable: allIssues().length > 1">Sort</button>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.issuelist { padding: 1em; background-color: #87CEEB; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.issuelist input { font-family: Arial; }
.issuelist b { font-weight: bold; }
.issuelist p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.issuelist select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.issuelist h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; }
```

js

```
var Issuelist = function () {
this.issueToAdd = ko.observable("");
this.allIssues = ko.observableArray(["test"]);
this.selectedIssues = ko.observableArray(["test"]);

this.addIssue = function () {
if ((this.issueToAdd() != "") && (this.allIssues.indexOf(this.issueToAdd()) < 0))
    this.allIssues.push(this.issueToAdd());
this.issueToAdd("");
};

this.removeSelected = function () {
this.allIssues.removeAll(this.selectedIssues());
this.selectedIssues([]);
};

this.sortIssues = function () {
this.allIssues.sort();
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new Issuelist());
```

Answer (score 1):

To run a function when the page is ready using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: so do i put the $(document).ready(function(){  at the begining of my js file and the } at the end?

Comment: You only want to wrap what you need to run when the document is loaded in that. If what you've posted is all your js file contains, then yes, the whole thing needs to be run on $(document).ready.